# Flask read file stream

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing the backend for a Flask application and the front end is sending a POST request to me with the file stream in multipart. I have the following code to just read the file:

```
from flask import request, jsonify, Flask
from flask.views import MethodView
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)
class ClassName(MethodView):
        def get(self):
                return "Data"
        def post(self):
            file_stream = request.files['file']
            file_stream.read()
            return file_stream

app.add_url_rule('/random', view_func = ClassName.as_view('random'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', port = 5001)
```

When I submit the post request, it outputs the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Probably your template cause the problem. What is your file input name. In your example it must be `file` : `<input type="file" name="file">`. Or share your template with us.

Comment: I checked my form, and you were right. Thank you!